# How add a label from header in ingress-nginx for prom metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-nginx

team I want to add as a label header in Mertic http_requests_total from ingress nginx is there a possible way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using helm deployment, you may check [ServiceMonitor](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml) from the helm values available.

```
prometheus-windows-exporter:
  ## Enable ServiceMonitor and set Kubernetes label to use as a job label
  ##
  prometheus:
    monitor:
      enabled: true
      jobLabel: jobLabel

  releaseLabel: true

  ## Set job label to 'windows-exporter' as required by the default Prometheus rules and Grafana dashboards
  ##
  podLabels:
    jobLabel: windows-exporter

  ## Enable memory and container metrics as required by the default Prometheus rules and Grafana dashboards
  ##
  config: |-
    collectors:
      enabled: '[defaults],memory,container'

## Configuration for alertmanager
## ref: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/alertmanager/
##
```

You may also configure the [ServiceMonitor](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md) for the endpoint you want to monitor as example below:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: example-app
  labels:
    team: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-app
  endpoints:
  - port: web
```